# Problemas con CRUD con Ajax / DataTable

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

He desarrollado un simple formulario usando DataTable JQuery con MVC (c#). Y mi problema es que recibo un objeto con sus atributos en null, no recibo el objeto que sale cargado desde el formulario. Y no me doy cuenta donde esta el error.
Código en la vista (desde donde sale el objeto):

```
function guardar(){
        var $data = {
            oPais: {
                id:parseInt($("#txtId").val()),
                nombre:$("#txtNombre").val(),
               }
            }
            console.log($data.oPais)
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: "@Url.Action("GuardarPais", "Pais")",
                type: "POST",
                data: JSON.stringify($data),
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) 
                {
                    if (data.resultado) {
                        tabla_pais.ajax.reload();
                        $('#FormData').modal('hide');
                    } else {
                        alert(data.id);
                        alert("No se pudo guardar los cambios");
                    }
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    console.log(error)
                },
                beforeSend: function () {

                }
            });
```

Función en el controlador:

```
[HttpPost]
        public JsonResult GuardarPais(Models.Pais oPais)
        {
            bool respuesta = true;
            Models.Pais obj = oPais;
            try
            {
                DAL.dalPais.Save(cadenaSQL, obj);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                respuesta = false;
            }

            return Json(new { resultado = respuesta });

        }
```

Aquí el oPais llega con sus atributos vacíos o nulos. Y esto es lo que no se resolver, poder recibir el objeto con sus datos, que al debbugear vi que ese objeto se carga, va al controler pero allí llega vacío.

Modal desde donde toma los datos:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="formData" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="modalTitle">ABM / Paices</h5>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label class="col-form-label">Id</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtId" disabled>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label class="col-form-label">Nombre</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtNombre">
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="guardar()">Guardar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Gracias por su atención

Comment: ¿Puedes poner el HTML correspondiente a los id txtId y txtNombre?

Comment: Listo @masterguru !!!! Ya edite y agregue lo que solisitaste. Gracias

Comment: Supongo que en tu código cierras bien la función **guardar()** porque en la pregunta te has descuidado una llave al final para cerrarla bien. Y tambien se supone que el id lo rellenas antes de enviar el formulario, porque no se puede editar al estar en disabled. ¿puedes poner como lo estas rellenando?

Comment: @masterguru controlo con: function guardar(){
        var $data = {
            oPais: {
                id:parseInt($("#txtId").val()),
                nombre:$("#txtNombre").val(),
               }
            }
            console.log($data.oPais)

Comment: Hasta este punto el objeto llega cargado

Comment: Al ver el consolo.log($data) veo el objeto cargado, lo paso a la propiedad data: JSON.stringify($data), y en el controlador me llega vacio ???

Comment: Pásale a través de una propiedad en el data, es decir, colócale algo como `data: { "Propiedad": JSON.stringify($data) } `

Comment: @lsanchezo provee esto y me llega vacío igual ....

Comment: Mmm déjalo enviándose como te dije, con el "Propiedad" y en el controlador coloca `GuardarPais(dynamic oPais)` porque está recibiendo un JSON, trata con ello.

Comment: @Isanchezo tengo problemas para castearlo: es correcto esto. me genera error:
**dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Models.Pais>(oPais);
    Models.Pais obj = (Models.Pais)data;**